# validity of auth token in OAuth2 in SharePoint App Registration/ Azure AD app

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-ad, sharepoint-app-registration

I have a SharePoint app registered in a site

To access the documents, I am getting the Auth Token from the below URL

```
https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/{{realm}}/tokens/OAuth/2
```

What is the validity of the auth token that we get from this URL?

I am not able to find the [validity](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims) of the token specified anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its valid for a day

in the response, I get

```
"expires_in": "86399"
```

which is 24 hours.